# Why can't I import Pandas in Python Worksheet?

Tags: pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I get this error when doing `import pandas as pd`.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "_udf_code.py", line 10, in
> main ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyarrow'  in function
> PYTHON_WORKSHEET with handler main

Is it not allowed to import pandas and do pandas manipulation in Snowflake?

Comment: Python worksheets support all the packages in Anaconda and that includes pandas and pyarrow - so there shouldn't be an issue. Please update your question to include the actual code you've written that is giving this error (or a minimal reproducible example) - as editable text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3rd Party packages are available via Anaconda channel and `pandas` is listed.

https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/snowflake/

---

[Using Third-Party Packages](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/python/udf-python-packages#getting-started)

> **Before you start using the packages provided by Anaconda inside Snowflake, you must acknowledge the Snowflake Third Party Terms.**
>
> > You must be the organization administrator (use the ORGADMIN role) to accept the terms. You only need to accept the terms once for your Snowflake account. Refer to Enabling the ORGADMIN Role for an Account.
>
> 1. Sign in to Snowsight.
> 2. Select **Admin » Billing & Terms.**
> 3. In the **Anaconda** section, select **Enable**.
> 4. In the **Anaconda Packages** dialog, click the link to review the Snowflake Third Party Terms page.
> 5. If you agree to the terms, select **Acknowledge & Continue.**

---

Python Worksheet:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Lukasz, could you comment on the performance of pandas dataframe manipulation vs Snowpark dataframe manipulation in Snowflake engine? Is it slower?