# Import Python Packages in SnowFlake to be Used Python Worksheets

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have successfully installed a Python package using the following guide:

https://medium.com/snowflake/running-pip-packages-in-snowflake-d43581a67439

However, the outcome is exactly what I was expecting.

I was hoping that after importing the Python Wheel into SnowFlake the package would appear here

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

But as you can see no packages were added.

I believe if the package was added as shown in the image I would be able to execute the following lines of code from a SnowFlake Python Worksheet:

```
from faker_biology.physiology import CellType, Organ, Organelle
from faker import Faker
```

But I keep on getting the error ModuleNotFoundError

So, can someone let me know how to add a Python Package that will accessible from a SnowFlake Python Worksheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could run it inside Python worksheet without any issues:

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark

from faker import Faker
import wheel_loader
    
def fake(locale,provider,parameters):
    wheel_loader.load('faker_biology-0.6.0-py3-none-any.whl')

    from faker_biology.physiology import CellType
      
    if type(parameters).__name__=='sqlNullWrapper':
        parameters = {}
    fake = Faker(locale=locale)
    fake.add_provider(CellType)
    return fake.format(formatter=provider,**parameters)

def main(session: snowpark.Session): 
    return fake('en_US','celltype',{})
```

Output:

| PYTHON_WORKSHEET |
| --- |
| Starburst amacrine cells |

---

Anaconda package:

[image]

Stage Packages:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Wow, @lukaz, that's amazing. I will try your code. I'm really struggling

Comment: Hi @lukaz, I have updated my question to show that I have successfully imported the faker_biology package, and I used your code, but I'm still getting the error 'No modue named 'faker' .. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Patterson I have already provided how to import "faker" on first screenshot. It is loaded via Anaconda packages. Please note that 3rd Party packages has to be enabled first on Account level: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75930933/5070879

Comment: "faker" is loaded via Anaconda as you mentioned, (see my update). This is why I'm confused that I'm getting the message 'No module named 'faker'

Comment: @Patterson Have you enabled 3rd Party packages as per my previous comment?

Comment: thanks for sticking with me on this question. I have updated my question to show that I have enabled 3rd Party packages as per your suggestion

Comment: I have noticed that sometimes there is a lag between selecting a package from a stage and when the worksheet recognizes it. But if you are still waiting for it, that seems unexpected.

Comment: I would simply close/reopen the worksheet and try run the code again

Comment: Wow, I got it to work. I needed to tick the 'faker' in the Anaconda packages.