Snowflake/ Snowpark "import sklearn" results in "no module found."
I'm using a python worksheet in Snowflake.
When I got to information_schema.packages, scikit-learn is clearly there and installed.
But when I reference 'sklearn' (don't really understand where this full-name vs. shortened name comes from, but sklearn is obviously the reference to scikit-learn package). It says module not found.
My understanding is that it's pre-installed with Snowpark. So what's the deal? What am I doing wrong?

Have you added this package in the Python Worksheet UI? - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75930933/5070879

I don't even see where this 'Anaconda Package" UI selector even is in the Snowflake worksheet. It's possible it's not enabled, but I'd be a bit surprised.

pandas reads just fine, so .... not sure the deal with sklearn. It's listed in information_schema.packages

Python Worksheet UI - Package - Anaconda

Oh .. that looks like it's working now. Well, another step closer at least. Any reason it must be selected in the IDE and there's no text way to do this? .... I'm guessing the Snowflake python IDE is probably not the best choice for now.

Package picker is a standard thing. In any case for more rich UI experience I suggest trying Snowflake Notebooks. It supports "environment.yml" where you can define dependencies in a "text way".

For Python Worksheet UI - Package Picker:


For Snowflake Notebooks:

Import package from Anaconda

or

environment.yml


